# Как узнать количество символов или строк в UI Text?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Как узнать количество символов или строк в `UI Text`?

Answer (score 2):

`UI Text` - это строка. А из строки получить количество символов можно например так:

```
string data = "Hello world!";
List<char> datalist = new List<char>();
datalist.AddRange(data);

Debug.Log(datalist.Count); // 12
```

или так

```
string str = "Hello world!";
char[] arr = str.ToCharArray(0, str.Length);
Debug.Log(arr.Length); // 12
```

и даже так:

```
string data = "Hello world!";
var dataLength = data.Length;
Debug.Log(dataLength);
```

---

P.S. Правда если надо не учитывать пробелы, то надо действовать слегка по-другому